# Prefill a DateTimeField from URL in django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

How to prefill a `DateTimeField` from URL in django admin?

Let's say your model is :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

Then you can have the model "Add" form prefilled with values by passing them as GET parameters to the add view like:

```
/admin/app/mymodel/add/?name=Test
```

This is a really cool feature but how do you achieve this for a DateTimeField?

I tried many possible formats without success.

**Update:**

It seems impossible to do because django admin uses a `SplitDateTimeWidget` for `DateTimeField`. But if you don't mind using a different widget and loosing the datepicker, you can use a `DateTimeInput` widget instead.

The fastest way is to add this to your `ModelAdmin` class:

```
formfield_overrides = {
    models.DateTimeField: {'widget': DateTimeInput},
}
```

Comment: I've found this 4 year old [ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9739) to be useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First define the serialization/deserialization format:

```
DATETIME_FORMAT="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Then when you want to open the admin url use it:

```
copiedArguments = {
   "fromDateTime": event.fromDateTime.strftime(DATETIME_FORMAT)
}
return HttpResponseRedirect(
            u"{}?{}".format(reverse('admin:events_event_add'), urllib.urlencode(copiedArguments)))
```

last but not least extract the datetime in the model admin:

```
def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
    initialData = super(EventAdmin, self).get_changeform_initial_data(request)
    initialData["fromDateTime"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(request.GET["fromDateTime"],DATETIME_FORMAT)
    return initialData
```

Answer (score 3):

The problems seems to be with the widget. A `DateField` would work fine with `?date=yyyy-mm-dd`, but a `DateTimeField` uses the `SplitDateTimeWidget`. It can not have a string as an initial value.

Maybe you could propose a patch to `SplitDateTimeWidget` to try to convert string values, or you could change the admin default widget for a `DateTimeField` (if that is possible).

Comment: Yes I could use a simple TextInput widget instead. I'm still trying to figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays there's the `get_changeform_initial_data` ModelAdmin method.

I'm passing the query parameters like this:
`?start=08/09/2022 12:30&end=08/09/2022 17:00`

And it works fine by overriding the method like that:

```py
    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        initial = super().get_changeform_initial_data(request)
        if "end" in initial:
            initial["end"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(initial["end"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        if "start" in initial:
            initial["start"] = datetime.datetime.strptime(initial["start"], "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
        return initial
```

It's also mentioned in [this issue's comment](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9739#comment:24), and useful for those facing the error `'str' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'` when trying to prefill a datetime field from query parameters in Django admin.